# Send $_POST data to Android Webview

Tags: php, android, ajax, json, jsonp

So I have this Android Application that's in WebView that should pass the data to a server(hosting site), unfortunately I can't do it so I need your help to solve this problem.

I got most of the code from this site so, it might looked familiar to you.

So I have this HTML file that initiate the function to send the data to a server.

**watch_video.html**

```
    var v_id = getUrlVars()["v_id"];

    $.ajax({

        url: "http://mysite.com/fbtest.php?json_callback=?",
        dataType: "jsonp text",       
        //GET method is used
        type: "POST",

        //pass the data         
        data: 'v_id=' + v_id,

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //Cross Domain
        crossDomain: true,

        //success
        success: function (html) {    
            alert(html);         
        }
```

So in PHP file which in a server(hosting site) that uses cross domain here's the code:

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$v_id = ($_POST['v_id']) ?$_POST['v_id'] : $_GET['v_id'];
$dwatch=date("Y-m-d");
$twatch=date("H:i:s");

$query="insert into watched_videos (fb_id,vid,date_watched,time_watched) values('12345','".$v_id."','".$dwatch."','".$twatch."')";
        $row = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

**I tested this locally using XAMPP, it works it inserted the data in a database.**

When I installed it in **Android**, and did the same function it **didn't worked.**

**Here's my MainActivity.java code:**

```
package namename.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mWebView = null;
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webtest);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/indexbackup.html");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView mWebView = null;
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webtest);
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

So going back to what I've said before I initiated the function in WebView using JSONP it did not work.

I was wondering if I have something to put in my android file or so.

I would be glad if someone helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not write code that directly puts post or get variables into a database. You should be using Prepared Statements in your PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with this line

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/indexbackup.html");
```

you have to give proper file path like a browser

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://yoursite/android_asset/www/indexbackup.html");
```

Comment: I don't know but, the html file is in a android application. 
So when I installed the application the file indexbackup.html is also installed in a android device.

Should I put the indexbackup.html in a hosting site along with the .php file?

Comment: if the html file don't do a server call then i will sugest it to put in your android application and if it does a server call then put it in your hosting server.

Comment: Thaaaanks! 
I never thought of putting it on hosting site I also modified my android file with some codes that I found in site, without your answer I would be stuck till now. I owe you one dude. Thanks. :)